# how to get a url from custom emojis from another servers and send it in the chat using discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I wanna make the bot to grab the emoji url and send it into the chat

```py
@client.command()
async def geturl(ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji):
    await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

That's the code i used and it works just fine as you can see here: [bot command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPzPj.png)

the problem is, I can't get it to work with emotes from other servers, the ones that you usually needs nitro to use it.
How can I add it into the code?

Comment: "I can't get it to work with emotes from other servers" doesn't help at all. What have you tried so far? What is the error message / traceback?

Comment: Sorry about that, but it gives me a BadArgument error with emotes that is not on the current server. I've heard that bots only have access to emothes they're in, so 'i'm not sure about where do I need to tweark to get it to work, all i tried was random stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to typehint emoji to `discord.PartialEmoji`, as the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#partialemoji) state: **Custom emoji that the bot cannot see from e.g. Message.reactions**

Below is the revised code:

```py
from typing import Union

@client.command()
async def geturl(ctx, emoji: Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji]):
    await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```